# Gmail error after generating csv file and sharing intent using Fileprovider: "Unable to attach file"

Tags: android, email, android-intent, fileprovider

I am creating an app which generates a csv file, and then sends it via email.

It does work if I choose Whatsapp, or Google Drive, but if I select Gmail, I get a toast "Unable to attach file".
In the Logcat, I get the following lines:

```
2020-05-16 16:03:43.518 30779-30779/? W/Gmail: Gmail:No collectionId found for event forward
2020-05-16 16:03:43.518 30779-30779/? W/Gmail: Gmail:No itemId found for event forward
```

So I suppose it is a problem with my path, but I cannot manage to figure out what is the issue.

See the code below:

```
        String today = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmm").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        //saving the file into device
        FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("Data_"+today+".csv", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        out.write(data.toString().getBytes());
        out.close();

        //exporting
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        File filelocation = new File(getFilesDir(), "Data_"+today+".csv");
        Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.aaaa.bbbb.fileprovider", filelocation);
        Intent fileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        fileIntent.setType("text/csv");
        String to[] = {"aaa@bbb.com"};
        fileIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,to);
        fileIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Data_"+today+".csv");
        fileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        fileIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"filelocation = " + filelocation.toString());
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Uri = " + path.toString());

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(fileIntent, "Send email"));
```

The file provider xml:

```
<paths>
<files-path
    name="data"
    path="."/>
</paths>
```

Here is the provider definition from the manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.aaaa.bbbb.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_path" />
</provider>
```

The log.d provides the following:

```
2020-05-16 16:16:40.745 2030-2030/com.aaaa.bbbb D/Export: filelocation = /data/user/0/com.aaaa.bbbb/files/Data_20200516_1616.csv
2020-05-16 16:16:40.745 2030-2030/com.aaaa.bbbb D/Export: Uri = content://com.aaaa.bbbb.fileprovider/data/Data_20200516_1616.csv
```

Any idea of what is wrong?

Comment: `fileIntent.setType("test/csv")`. Do you mean text/csv? Try other mime types. Try for instance text/plain.

Comment: sorry for the typo. I tried "text/csv", "text /plain", "text/text", and the result is the same with Gmail.

Comment: What you want is pretty basic. Can you attach an image?

Comment: `The file provider xml:` You are sure the file is res/xml/provider_path.xml ?

Comment: yes the file provider xml is the file res/xml/provider_path.xml

Comment: I dont know why Gmail is obstructing. Try another email client.

Comment: You said it does not work with Gmail.

Comment: @blackapps, I tested with the following so far:
- works fine with: Bluemail, Whatsapp, Google Drive, LINE;
- "unable to attach file " with: Gmail, Samsung email

Comment: Did you work it out? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: No, I have not find a solution for now